# DLL implementing window hook crashes with "Faulting module name: myDll.DLL_unloaded"

Tags: windows, hook

I have a DLL which uses certain hook functions, and it works OK on Windows 7 and XP. But on Windows 8, i get a crash when I cloase IE 10 or some other program.

> Faulting module name: myDll.DLL_unloaded

Can you please tell me why this happens and how to fix it?

By the way, if I run a program, such as IE, with admin privileges or in the Windows 7 or XP compatible mode, it won't crash.

Here is part of my code:

```
if (checkWorking())
{
  addString2File("C:\\dll.txt", "core online");
  // TRACE("core online!");
  HHOOK hHook = ::SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, WindowHook, g_hModule, NULL);
  ::PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_NULL, 0, 0);

  tools::security::SecurityAllAccess sa;
  HANDLE hSleepEvent = ::CreateEvent(sa, TRUE, FALSE, g_tszTermEventName);
  tools::security::GrantLowIntegrityAccess(SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, hSleepEvent);
  tools::endsession::WaitEndSession(hSleepEvent);
  ::UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
}
else
{
  TRACE("wrong start!");
}
```

Comment: Windows protects itself against mis-behaving windows hooks.  The kind that throw exceptions in the hook callback or take too long to process the callback.  You can assume it is a problem with Windows but that's not going to get you anywhere.  Asking the question this way and describing *nothing* about your callback implementation isn't going to get you anywhere either.

Comment: Your DLL was still executing code at the point you removed the hook, so you yanked the rug out from under yourself. Remap the symbols for your DLL and that will tell you what you were doing when the hook was unloaded. That may give you a clue what you're doing wrong. (My guess is that your hook creates a thread and you did not bump your DLL reference count.)